# Failed to apply google app engine plugin in Gradle

Tags: spring-mvc, google-app-engine, jakarta-ee, gradle, build.gradle

I am doing an application using spring and Google app engine using Gradle build frame work. Here i am getting issue like `Failed to apply plugin [id 'appengine']`.

My gradle version is 2.14.1

This is my build.gradle code

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin:'war'
apply plugin: 'tangram'
apply plugin: 'appengine'


sourceCompatibility = 1.7
version = '1.0'
jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Example', 'Implementation-Version': version
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    mavenLocal()
}

//for saving images in cloud

/*repositories{
    maven{
        url "http://gmultipart.googlecode.com/svn/repo/m2"
    }
}*/

appengine {
    httpPort = 8899
    downloadSdk = true
    httpAddress = '0.0.0.0'
//  stopPort = 8999
//  stopKey = 'STOP'
    jvmFlags = ['-Xdebug', '-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8889',
    '-Ddatastore.backing_store=C:/gae/Example/local_db.bin']

    appcfg {
        email = 'yourmail@gmail.com'
        oauth2 = true
    }
        enhancerVersion = "v2"
        enhancerApi = "jpa"
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mgoellnitz/artifacts/master" 
            }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.9'
        // for Enhancer
        classpath 'tangram:gradle-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-backports-compat23:2.3.5'
    }
}

configurations {
 jpa {
     extendsFrom compile
 }
}

// JPA with DataNucleus
compileJava.doLast {
  nucleusJpaEnhance()
}


dependencies {

    // Google app engine multi file upload
    //compile group: 'gmultipart', name: 'gmultipart', version: '0.4'

    // Google Cloud Storage jar - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/download
    //compile 'com.google.appengine.tools:appengine-gcs-client:0.4.1'

    compile group: 'commons-collections', name: 'commons-collections', version: '3.2'

    // Repo Jars
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-core:3.1.3'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-api-jpa:3.1.3'
    compile 'com.google.appengine.orm:datanucleus-appengine:2.1.2'
    compile 'org.datanucleus:datanucleus-enhancer:3.1.1'
    compile 'org.apache.geronimo.specs:geronimo-jpa_2.0_spec:1.0'

// Spring
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-tx:4.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-orm:4.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-aspects:4.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-web:4.0.2.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework:spring-support:2.0.8'

    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:3.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:3.2.3.RELEASE'
    compile 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:3.2.3.RELEASE'


    //guava
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'

    //dozer
    compile  'net.sf.dozer:dozer:5.3.2'

    // Lom bok
    compile 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.12.2'

    // Jackson
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.13'

    // GAE
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.appengine/appengine-java-sdk
    appengineSdk 'com.google.appengine:appengine-java-sdk:1.9.40'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk:1.9.40'
    compile 'com.google.appengine:appengine-api-labs:1.9.40'

    // Servlet
    // compile 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'


    //log4j
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12
    compile group: 'org.slf4j', name: 'slf4j-log4j12', version: '1.7.21'

    //twilio for SMS
    // compile 'com.twilio.sdk:twilio-java-sdk:3.4.2'


     //file upload
    // commons-collection
    // 'commons-collections:commons-collections:20040616',
    // 'commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:1.2.2',
    // 'org.apache.commons:commons-io:1.3.2',

     // jstl
      compile 'jstl:jstl:1.2'
      runtime "javax.servlet:jstl:1.2"

     //mail
     compile 'javax.mail:mail:1.5.0-b01'
     compile 'javax.activation:activation:1.1-rev-1'

     // PDF generation libs
     //compile 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-core:9.0.6'
     //compile 'org.xhtmlrenderer:flying-saucer-pdf:9.0.6'
    // compile 'com.itextpdf:itextpdf:5.5.2'
    // compile 'com.itextpdf.tool:xmlworker:5.5.2'
}

test
    {
     systemProperties 'property': 'value'
     }

uploadArchives {
    repositories {
            flatDir {
            dirs 'repos'
             }
         }
    }
```

And below one is full stack trace which i am getting exactly.

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Example'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'appengine']
   > No such property: model for class: org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.EclipsePlugin

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Example'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:177)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:77)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:182)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:540)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:93)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:124)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:121)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'appengine']
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:153)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.apply(DefaultPluginManager.java:112)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyType(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:113)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:136)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.java:34)
        at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
        at build_bvoq4s56y5u8xb8437q32zs1h.run(/Users/venu/git/onslider_ionic_server/OnSliderServer/build.gradle:5)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 47 more
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: model for class: org.gradle.plugins.ide.eclipse.EclipsePlugin
        at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin$_addEclipseConfigurationForFunctionalTestRuntimeConfiguration_closure32.doCall(AppEnginePlugin.groovy:654)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$FilteredAction.execute(Actions.java:205)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.all(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:115)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.DefaultDomainObjectCollection.withType(DefaultDomainObjectCollection.java:126)
        at org.gradle.api.DomainObjectCollection$withType$0.call(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin.addEclipseConfigurationForFunctionalTestRuntimeConfiguration(AppEnginePlugin.groovy:653)
        at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin.this$2$addEclipseConfigurationForFunctionalTestRuntimeConfiguration(AppEnginePlugin.groovy)
        at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin.addFunctionalTestConfigurationsAndSourceSet(AppEnginePlugin.groovy:637)
        at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin.this$2$addFunctionalTestConfigurationsAndSourceSet(AppEnginePlugin.groovy)
        at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin.configureFunctionalTest(AppEnginePlugin.groovy:602)
        at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin.this$2$configureFunctionalTest(AppEnginePlugin.groovy)
        at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin.apply(AppEnginePlugin.groovy:159)
        at com.google.appengine.AppEnginePlugin.apply(AppEnginePlugin.groovy)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.applyImperative(ImperativeOnlyPluginApplicator.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.RuleBasedPluginApplicator.applyImperative(RuleBasedPluginApplicator.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginManager.doApply(DefaultPluginManager.java:137)
        ... 57 more


BUILD FAILED
```

Can any one help me out from this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which Java version you are using..?

Comment: Did you set path for Gradle and GRADLE_HOME?

Comment: yeah i have gradle and GRADLE_HOME path

Comment: Did you set path for JAVA_HOME??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have u tried with differnent version , I mean latest gradle appengine plugin ?

> classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.9'

To:

> classpath 'com.google.appengine:gradle-appengine-plugin:1.9.42'

Ref: [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gradle-appengine-plugin)

That should solve the problem.